# How to install python commpy package in windows 10?

Tags: python, installation, package

I tried to install "commpy" package via cmd window:

```
pip install commpy
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement commpy
ERROR: No matching distribution found for commpy
```

I got similar errors while trying to install package "fractions". However, numpy can be installed easily using pip. I have already updated pip and I am using python3.

Comment: Are you using Virtual Enviroments? If not, please start to creating one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either search on pypi server:

https://pypi.org/search/?q=commpy

or with pip command:

```sh
$ pip search commpy
scikit-commpy (0.5.0)  - Digital Communication Algorithms with Python
```

No module is just called `commpy`.

Comment: How to import this package? I used: "import commpy" and "import scikit-commpy", but none of them work.

Comment: `import commpy` worked for me. Maybe you have more that one Python installed in your system?

Comment: Yes, import commpy is OK now. Thank you.